# Transalate .htaccess allow deny rules to IIS rewrite rules

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

I have no access to IIS manager so I need to edit the Web.config files.

I had trouble translating this kinds of rules:

```
<Limit GET>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from .comodomain.com
</Limit>
```

Into IIS rewrite rules. Does anybody have some clue¿?

Comment: You'll need [Security Authorization <authorization>](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/authorization) and you might also want the [Request Filtering role service](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering) installed/enabled

Answer (score -1):

Use this instead.
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/request-blocking-rule-template

if you can't find the URL rewrite, you can download it from iis.net

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to do this with a little more detail? Will make your answer much stronger!

Comment: Please put more detail into your answers.  A quick summary of what is on the link you provided is best.  Your answer should be useful if that like dies in the future.